# Full Screen - Libre Office Impress

Tags: fullscreen, libreoffice-impress

I'm trying to select the fullscreen function in Libre Office Impress without enabling the slide function.
I want to be able to type and edit my work without the title bar or time or turning on the slides.
I have tried `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `J` but it won't work as it only works on Writer or Calc.
I'm open to any suggestions that may help me.

Comment: Short answer: It's not possible.

Comment: OK, but how was my other answer not a answer but a comment?

Comment: And is there like an add-on or something, to do fullscreen?

Comment: Because a/ it doesn't answer the question b/ you are asking for more info (that belongs in a comment not an answer).

Comment: Asking for add-ons is off-topic.

Comment: Ok, so then why does LibreOficce Impress doesn't have a full screen but Writer or Calc does?